# Concurrency-How to start one thread, then start another one and first thread keeps running when thread 2 running?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to start log first, which will record the running steps and take long time. But other thread won't start until log finished. Is there any technical to solve my problem?
Actually I have read some sample code about CyclicBarrier and CountDownLatch. But I am not sure which class should use.

Finally, I figured out how, and it works!

```
public boolean execute(ExecuteArguments args)
{

    Thread logcat = new Thread(new LogCatsStart());
    Thread runner = new Thread(new TestCaseStart());
    logcat.start();
    runner.start();
    try
    {
        logcat.join();
        runner.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;

}

class LogCatsStart implements Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        tag = String.format("%s_%s_%s_%s", Utilities.getCurrentTime("MM-dd_hh-mm-ss"),
                testCaseName, "Iteration", iteration);
        collectLogCat();
        System.out.println("Done");

    }
}

class TestCaseStart implements Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        executeTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a threadpool? Show the code you have, we can't blindly guess.

Comment: Show your code because it's unlikely to get answered without seeing what's going on.

Comment: `CountDownLatch` has been mentioned but you might also want to look at `CyclicBarrier`.

Answer (score 1):

From the description given, I think you can continue the operation in the same thread, there is no need to start a second thread if the first one ends.

In case you don't need to stop the logging, you could share a `CountDownLatch` between the two and do `latch.countDown()` in the first thread when logging finishes and `latch.await()` at the very beginning of the second thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Here is simple example, where b thread wait  a thread :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Example {

    private static CountDownLatch cdl;

    public static void main(String ... s){
        cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("started a");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cdl.countDown();
                System.out.println("stoped a");
            }
        });
        Thread b = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("started b");
                System.out.println("wait a");
                try {
                    cdl.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("stoped b");
            }
        });
        b.start();
        a.start();
    }
}
```

output:

```
started b
wait a
started a
stoped a
stoped b
```